# Javascript fechas

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas a todos, tenia la siguiente pregunta, ¿se puede hacer que cuando un `input type="date`" hayan pasado mas de 65 años de diferencia entre la fecha de hoy y la que pusieron los usuarios, se desactivara un `input type="radio"`?

Es decir, en primer lugar necesito sacar el valor del campo "date", y después restarle a la fecha de hoy la fecha introducida, y si da mayor de 65 años de diferencia, que un campo de tipo radio se desactive, ¿Seria eso posible?

Comment: Sí. Con javascript y un evento en el input date. Si compartes tu código se te puede ayudar de manera específica. Un saludo!

Comment: Es que, ese es el problema, que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, nunca use Javascripts, siempre PHP

Comment: ten en cuenta que input type date no vale en IE10 o anterior

Comment: Vaya lois6b, no tenia ni idea de eso... me parece que eso sera un problema grave, aunque tambien me bastaria  con decir que no soportamos ese explorador, el caso es, muchisimas gracias, no tenia ni idea de eso, me tocara avisarlo mas adelante, gracias de nuevo

Comment: @PepeJuan, si es imperioso usar IE10 o anterior, puedes usar el datepicker de jQuery, que si está soportado http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @PepeJuan No te preocupes por IE10, 0.87% global usage; IE9, 0.91% global usage; IE8 1.18% global usage; IE7, 0.05% global usage. Total < 3%.

Comment: @PepeJuan si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ahi tienes el codigo HTML y Javascript. Creo que es claro pero si tienes dudas pregunta ^^

En vez de un boton, puedes hacer un evento OnChange del `type="date"`

El calculo que figura en el IF es porque el resultado te lo da en milisegundos y lo paso a años.

```js
function bloquearRadio(){

    var fechaInput = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value); 
    var dateNow = Date.now();
    if((dateNow - fechaInput)/(1000 * 3600 * 24*365) > 65 ){
    //alert("+65");
        document.getElementById("radio").disabled = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("radio").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form >
  Fecha:
  <input id="fecha" type="date" >
  <input onclick=bloquearRadio() type="button" value="Validar Fecha">

  <input id="radio" type="radio" >No activo para más de 65 años </input>

</form>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!! lo probare en cuanto tenga tiempo, pero me parece increible y facil de entender, muchas gracias c:

Answer (score 6):

El código **JavaScript** (con algo de **jQuery**) sería el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {document  
  $("#comprobar").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var hoy = new Date();
    var fecha_introducida = $("input[name='fecha']").val();
    fecha_introducida = new Date(fecha_introducida);
    diferencia = hoy.getFullYear() - fecha_introducida.getFullYear();
    alert("Diferencia de años: "+diferencia);

    if (diferencia > 65){
      $('input[name=radioB]').attr('disabled',true);
    }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="fecha_input">
    <input type="date" name="fecha">
    <input name="radioB" type="radio"> Menos de 65 años de diferencia<br>
    <button id="comprobar">Comprobar</button>
</form>
```

Para cargar **jQuery** en tu documento no olvides añadirlo en la etiqueta `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si no comprendes alguna parte del código no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Wow, es asombroso, me habeis salvado la vida omg :D