# Comparar dos fechas en javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo igualar dos fechas en `JavaScript`? Determinar si son iguales, o si una es mayor que otra. Los valores los estoy obteniendo de `inputs` de texto.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Javascript fechas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29871/javascript-fechas). No es exactamente igual pero ves como comparar y ver cual es mayor que otra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En javascript existe algo llamado Date object. Con getTime() puedes obtener los valores y compararlos unos con otros Usando === , ==!, > , < , etc. Por ejemplo:

```
var fechauno = new Date();
var fechados = new Date(fechauno);
var resultado = fechauno.getTime() === fechados.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que necesitas saber respecto a las fechas es que para pasar un String a Date solo tienes que crear un objeto tipo Date pasándole como argumento el String de la fecha. Cuando tengas el objeto Date ya puedes obtener el tiempo con el método getTime del objeto Date, y compararlo con el getTime de otro objeto Date como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
if( (new Date('primera fecha').getTime() > new Date('segunda fecha').getTime()))
    {
      "Hacer algo"
    }
```

Comment: Hola Erlantz, deberias añadir explicacion a parte de pegar codigo. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Tienes razón, lo siento, ¡lo haré a partir de ahora!

Comment: No hace falta que te disculpes. Aun estás a tiempo. Siempre puedes editar para mejorar tu publicación. Un saludo.

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo, por favor **[edit] tu respuesta** agregando una expliación sobre ese código. Por favor revisa: **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.